# Probability of birthdays of seven girlfriends

Tags: probability

If a person has seven girlfriends, what is the probability of them having birthdays on seven different days on a particular week?

Number of ways gf's can have birthdays on different days is $7!$

Total number of ways they can have birthdays on a particular week is $7^7$

Hence the answer is $\cfrac{7!}{7^7}$

Is my analysis correct?

Comment: Good thing the genders were specified—that's crucial to the problem. /eyeroll

Comment: Sorry to be that guy, but _seven_ girlfriends? Really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your wording is somewhat confusing.  If I take your question at face value, the probability that the first girlfriend will have a birthday during a particular (particular being the key condition) week is:  7 days in particular week/365 possible birthdays (in non leap years anyways) = 7/365.  The odds that the second girlfriend will have a birthday during the same particular week but on a different day is 6 available days in particular week/365 possible days that her birthday is = 6/365. Similarly the third girlfriend would be 5/365 and so on.  So, as you have worded it, the formula would be 7!/365^7.

However, if you meant "what is the probability that each of the seven girlfriends have birthdays on different weekdays in a given year, your answer is correct.  Not sure about your analysis though. You can arrive at 7!/7^7 if you calculate the odds that each additional girlfriend does not share a birthday (as in day of the week)

1st   7/7  7 available weekdays/7 possible weekdays

2nd   6/7  6 available weekdays/7 possible weekdays

3rd   5/7  5 available weekdays/7 possible weekdays

etc.

-->  7!/7^7

Answer (score 0):

There may be some reasons to suspect the probability is not uniformly distributed as usually a person does not have a completely arbitrary taste or objective with this endeavour. So if we know nothing more about this guy we can't say anything about the probability. Could even be a weird bet assuring a 100% chance. I.e. he would not even try to gf girl #7 once he knew she was the second Mondayer.

> Hey dudes I bet X bucks I can get one girlfriend every day of the week!